# Combine multiple PDF files into one document side-by-side in one row

Tags: pdf-format

How can I arrange three PDF figures (produced by Mathematica) in pdf format side by side (or two figures above and one below), similar to the image (source: doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.108.032010) attached herewith, and export in PDF format? Is it possible to achieve this using Mathematica without causing any distortion to the images? Thanks in advance for your guidance.

[image]

Comment: Import the PDF and then use "Row" or "Column"